# How to test Google Recaptcha v3 for getting low score?

Tags: recaptcha-v3

I have tested with Google Chrome Selenium addon but no luck. I have tried more than 50 times but no luck. I got only 15 low score(0.3 is 13 times and 0.1 is 2 times) out of 300 requests in my graph. Let me know if anyone got low score for consistent testing scenario.